# How to return a method's fully-qualified name on the fly?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Store/

        public string Index()
        {
            return "MvcMusicsStore.Controllers.StoreController.Index";
        }

    }
}
```

How to return a method's fully-qualified name on the fly?

Comment: Which version of C# are you using? C# 5 makes this simpler.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without any hard coding? Something like maybe?

```
public string Index()
{
    return GetType().FullName + GetMemberName();
}

static string GetMemberName([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
    return memberName;
}
```

Or perhaps prettier:

```
public string Index()
{
    return GetMemberName(this);
}

static string GetMemberName(
    object caller, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
    return caller.GetType().FullName + "." + memberName;
}
```

(I used `static` because I assume in the real code you'd want to put the method in a utility class somewhere)

Comment: Sorry. What is `[CallerMemberName] string memberName = ""`? It seems to be a new feature.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ yes, it is a new feature of C# 5; [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx)

Comment: @MarcGravell I wish there was a `[CallerType]` attribute or, because that might not be easy to do compile-time (?), at least something like `[CallerFullName]`.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy I suspect the reason that there *isn't* is because it doesn't solve the same type of problem: `this`, `this.GetType()` and `typeof(TheClass)` all exist, and none of those suffer quite the same problems as having to code `"SomeMethodName"` into call-sites.

Comment: @MarcGravell Except the caller has to explicitly provide `this`, whereas the `[Caller*]` attributes add the info without the caller having to do anything. But in case of the type it's definitely better than having to do `new StackFrame(1)` to figure out the method name...

Answer (score 7):

If you're using C# 5 you can do this slightly more simply, but this works too:

```
var method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
var type = method.DeclaringType;
var fullName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", type.FullName, method.Name);
```

That's assuming the method isn't overridden, of course. Unfortunately you can't put this into a utility method of course, as otherwise the current method is the utility method.

You can use [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) to get round this, but you need to be careful around inlining - if you create a utility method and then call it from within a method which is itself inlined, you'll get the *caller* of the method you want :(